# Exception not caught by assertRaises

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a unit test that checks for exception in constructor:

```
import unittest
from jaboci import Jacobi

class TestJacobi(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_even(self):
        a = 11
        n = 12
        Jacobi(a, n)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, Jacobi, a, n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The class under test:

```
class Jacobi:

    def __init__(self, a, n):
        self.a = a
        self.n = n
        if n % 2 == 0:
            raise ValueError("N must be odd.")
```

When i run unittest with `-m unittest discover`, the test fails:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_even (test_jacobi.TestJacobi)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prasopes/prg/python/PycharmProjects/jacobi_symbol/test_jacobi.py", line 9, in test_even
    Jacobi(a, n)
  File "/home/prasopes/prg/python/PycharmProjects/jacobi_symbol/jaboci.py", line 7, in __init__
    raise ValueError("N must be odd.")
ValueError: N must be odd.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Did you mean to `import jaboci` instead of `import jacobi`?

Comment: @abarnert it's a typo in the file name, thanks for pointing that out. I used autocompletion in my IDE so I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `Jacobi(a, n)` before `self.assertRaises(ValueError, Jacobi, a, n)`. The exception you get is from this first call, so the test immediately fails. It never reaches the line with `assertRaises`.

Comment: +1. I suspect the OP actually wanted to do `Jacobi(n, a)` (which succeeds), then `assertRaises(ValueError, Jacobi, a, n)` (which fails as expected). If you do that, the tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

[Since I don't have enough rep to comment on @mata answer...]

Just to be clear, you either need to

- remove `Jacobi(a, n)` [implied by @mata]
- or, call 'Jacobi(n, a)' [as posited by @abarnert comment to @mata]